# Should I use bonus damage on a high damage skill or a low damage skill?

Tags: soul-worker

I recently started playing a game called Soul Worker. The game has vertical skill bonuses. If you use a skill on the horizontal row then the next skill in the vertical column will show in the bottom skill bar. If you use the next skill within a time limit you will get a damage bonus. The first bonus is 4% the next bonus is 8%.

Should I put my weakest skill on the 8% damage slot or should I put my strongest skill? The skill damage in the game is percentage based so the skill damage is based off of the attack damage. 100 attack damage so the skill would do 170% of that damage.

[image]